# Google Maps API - Adding a fusion table layer to a styled map layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am very new to coding, I haven't really worked with it at all before, and was tasked with creating a custom map on which I can also show a number of markers. I have been succesful in making a map that show the markers and another map with the custom style. However, I can't figure out how to combine these two together.

Currently I have this, which displays the styled map but not the markers and I am completely clueless on how to move on from here.

```
function initMap() {

var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
  [
    {elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#C6BBB2'}]},
    {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#523735'}]},
    {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#f5f1e6'}]},
    {
      featureType: 'administrative',
      elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
      stylers: [{color: '#C6BBB2'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
      elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
      stylers: [{color: '#dcd2be'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
      elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
      stylers: [{color: '#ae9e90'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'landscape.natural',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [{color: '#C1B4AB'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'poi',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [{color: '#C6BBB2'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'poi',
      elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
      stylers: [{color: '#93817c'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'poi.park',
      elementType: 'geometry.fill',
      stylers: [{color: '#D3D3D3'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'poi.park',
      elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
      stylers: [{color: '#788F88'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'road',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [{color: '#FFB9C5'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'road.arterial',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [{color: '#FFB9C5'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'road.highway',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [{color: '#FFB9C5'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'road.highway',
      elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
      stylers: [{color: '#FF6D82'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [{color: '#FFB9C5'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
      elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
      stylers: [{color: '#FF906D'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'road.local',
      elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
      stylers: [{color: '#806b63'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'transit.line',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'transit.line',
      elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
      stylers: [{color: '#8f7d77'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'transit.line',
      elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
      stylers: [{color: '#ebe3cd'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'transit.station',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [{color: '#C6BBB2'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'water',
      elementType: 'geometry.fill',
      stylers: [{color: '#BAC6C2'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'water',
      elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
      stylers: [{color: '#BAC6C2'}]
    }
  ],
  {name: 'Styled Map'});

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: 59.329314, lng: 18.068579},
zoom: 10,
mapTypeControlOptions: {
  mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'satellite', 'hybrid', 'terrain',
          'styled_map']
}
});
map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);
map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');
}

var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
query: {
  select: 'X',
  from: '1GofM5ligrJNdXrv3wtJ8FMVeHIS5uGMJ85-SzoCF'
    }
  });
```

Any suggestions would be very appreciated as I am very very new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layer instance should be inside the initMap function, and you need to set the map of that layer.

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
      select: 'X',
      from: '1GofM5ligrJNdXrv3wtJ8FMVeHIS5uGMJ85-SzoCF'
  }
});

layer.setMap(map);
```

See working example here: http://jsbin.com/yajuxoj/edit?html,css,js,output

Here is the code of the sample app, you can also see and check the sample here by running the code snippet:

```js
function initMap() {

    var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
        [{
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#C6BBB2'
                }]
            },
            {
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#523735'
                }]
            },
            {
                elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#f5f1e6'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'administrative',
                elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#C6BBB2'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
                elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#dcd2be'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#ae9e90'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'landscape.natural',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#C1B4AB'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'poi',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#C6BBB2'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'poi',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#93817c'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'poi.park',
                elementType: 'geometry.fill',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#D3D3D3'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'poi.park',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#788F88'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'road',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#FFB9C5'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'road.arterial',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#FFB9C5'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'road.highway',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#FFB9C5'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'road.highway',
                elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#FF6D82'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#FFB9C5'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
                elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#FF906D'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'road.local',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#806b63'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'transit.line',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#dfd2ae'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'transit.line',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#8f7d77'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'transit.line',
                elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#ebe3cd'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'transit.station',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#C6BBB2'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'water',
                elementType: 'geometry.fill',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#BAC6C2'
                }]
            },
            {
                featureType: 'water',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#BAC6C2'
                }]
            }
        ], {
            name: 'Styled Map'
        });

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: 59.329314,
            lng: 18.068579
        },
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'satellite', 'hybrid', 'terrain',
                'styled_map'
            ]
        }
    });

    map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);
    map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');
  
    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
          select: 'X',
          from: '1GofM5ligrJNdXrv3wtJ8FMVeHIS5uGMJ85-SzoCF'
      }
   });
   layer.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sample</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCKQX3cyZ7pVKmBwE8wiowivW9qH62AVk8&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm!

Comment: If my answer helped you, you could also accept my answer so that it could help me and others as well :)